# Add footer widgets

Tags: widgets, footer

My website is running on WordPress theme which does not have options to add footer widgets.

How can I add it using other ways?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to make a child theme from the chosen theme and alter only the footer template to add additional sidebars. You can prepare additional sidebars in the child themes function.php and add them to any template you need altered.